# como recorrer una lista crear un rango con ciclo for con 2 variables input() ,python

Tags: python

me piden un programa que arroje un rango de ventas, teniendo ya los valores de esas ventas en variables en una lista, el usuario debe colocar el inicio y final de rango a consultar , y se imprima el rango de ventas, por ejemplo que el usuario pida las ventas del 2015 al 20120 , lo otro que tengo la duda de como recorrer y sacar ese rango mediante el ciclo un ciclo for ,ya seria algo parecido a esto :

ista_ventas=[venta_2010,venta_2011,venta_2012,venta_2013,venta_2014,venta_2015,venta_2016,venta_2018,venta_2019,venta_2020,venta_2021,venta_2022]

for i in range (len(lista_ventas)):
for  j in   range (len(lista_ventas)):

```
inicio_rango =(input("ingrese el año de inico del rango a evaluar  :") 
final_rango=(input("ingrese ingrese el año final del rango a evaluar: ") 

 print(f"las ventas desde  ese rango son  son {lista_ventas[i:j]"}
```

de esta forma me da error para sacar el rango

Comment: Creo que tu pregunta no es muy clara, intenta añadir más info.

Comment: A tu pregunta le falta un poco más de sentido, no se entiendo que es lo que quieres con el título. Los elementos de tu listado corresponden a use tipo de dato? Es una variable de cual no tenemos conocimiento.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que capto la idea, así que intentaré responder.

**Paso 1: Agregar las comillas**

Dado que cada elemento de tu lista ventas es un string, cada uno debería ir entre comillas:

```
lista_ventas=['venta_2010','venta_2011','venta_2012','venta_2013','venta_2014','venta_2015','venta_2016','venta_2017','venta_2018','venta_2019','venta_2020','venta_2021','venta_2022']
```

**Paso 2: Pedirle la información al usuario**

Esto ya lo tienes:

```
inicio_rango = input("ingrese el año de inicio del rango a evaluar: ") 
final_rango = input("ingrese ingrese el año final del rango a evaluar: ")
```

**Paso 3: Buscamos los rangos que ingresó el usuario en la lista**

Si el usuario pone '2014' como rango de inicio y buscamos ese valor en la lista, no lo vamos a encontrar porque no hay un elemento en la lista que se llame exactamente '2014'. Ahora bien, nosotros sabemos que sí existe un elemento llamado 'venta_2014' y que ese corresponde al año 2014, por lo tanto debemos tener esto en cuenta para buscar las ventas de un año en particular en la lista. Es decir, tenemos que concatenar los valores que nos dio el usuario con el prefijo 'venta_':

```
rango_minimo = 'venta_'+ inicio_rango
rango_maximo = 'venta_'+ final_rango
```

Ya teniendo esto, podemos buscar en qué posición de la lista se encuentran los valores que pidió el usuario. Esto lo hacemos con el método index() que lo que hace es encontrar la posición de un elemento determinado en una lista. (Advertencia: si hay dos valores iguales en la lista, este método sólo da la posición del primero que encuentre. Como observo que no hay valores repetidos en lista_ventas, me permito utilizarlo.)

```
indice_minimo = lista_ventas.index(rango_minimo)
indice_maximo = lista_ventas.index(rango_maximo)
```

**Paso 4: Recorrer la lista y obtener el rango de ventas deseado por el usuario**

Utilizamos las posiciones que obtuvimos en el paso anterior para indicarle a la función for i in range desde dónde debe empezar a recorrer la lista y donde parar. Y creamos una lista nueva en donde se van a almacenar los valores de las ventas, gracias al método append() que añade los elementos que le indiques al final de la lista. Aquí le estamos indicando que añada el elemento de la lista_ventas que se encuentra en la posicion i. Y ya con esto, el usuario obtiene las ventas anuales que se generaron en el rango de su interés.

```
lista_rangos = []
for i in range(indice_minimo,(indice_maximo+1)):
    lista_rangos.append(lista_ventas[i])
print("las ventas desde ese rango son:"+ str(lista_rangos))
```